# How do I keep a Angularjs text box in pristine state on initial load?

Tags: angularjs

I know I am missing something simple but when I load my view for a new entity, any inputs marked with 'required' are validated immediately.  This is before I touch any part of the form.  I am using v1.2.0-RC1

Here is some code:

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="item.name" required />
    <span class="validation-error" ng-show="form.name.$error.required">*Required</span>
    <button ng-click="post()">save</button>
</form>
```

Note: I add my form view via directive and use $compile.

```
MyApp.directive('loadForm', function($compile, $http){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            $scope.$watch(attr.loadForm, function(old, new){
            if(old != new){
                $http.get('myUrl').success(function(response){
                    var elem = angular.element(response);
                    var result = $compile(elem)(scope);
                    element.html(result);
                });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You could use `$dirty` => `ng-show="form.name.$error.required && form.name.$dirty"` should work I believe

Comment: I just tried that and it does work. Thank you.  It just seems like the "pristine" state should check if the form or field has not been touched yet and then decide whether to validate.